# How to parameterize c# classes

Tags: c#

When we write tests in JUnit, we can parameterize all the tests of a class. If I have 4 test methods in my class, and 5 parameters, I'll have 20 test runs.

In Java we would have something like

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;

import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PrimeNumberCheckerTest {
   private Integer inputNumber;
   private Boolean expectedResult;
   private PrimeNumberChecker primeNumberChecker;

   @Before
   public void initialize() {
      primeNumberChecker = new PrimeNumberChecker();
   }

   // Each parameter should be placed as an argument here
   // Every time runner triggers, it will pass the arguments
   // from parameters we defined in primeNumbers() method

   public PrimeNumberCheckerTest(Integer inputNumber, Boolean expectedResult) {
      this.inputNumber = inputNumber;
      this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
   }

   @Parameterized.Parameters
   public static Collection primeNumbers() {
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
         { 2, true },
         { 6, false },
         { 19, true },
         { 22, false },
         { 23, true }
      });
   }

   // This test will run 4 times since we have 5 parameters defined
   @Test
   public void testPrimeNumberChecker() {
      System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + inputNumber);
      assertEquals(expectedResult, 
      primeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));
   }
}
```

I want something similar in C#. I have a set of variables that are shared between all my tests methods (because they are big, and take some time to run, so it would be very slow to instantiate due to IO for each test). But I would like to change to run my test class mutiple time, changing the test class parameters each time.

In C#, we have the option of DataRows. But the parameters are only used for one method, not all methods:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

    [DataRow("C:/Users/path1", 10)]
    [DataRow("C:/Users/path", 20)]
    [TestMethod]
    public void AdditionTest(string path, int expectedResult)
    {
        MySlowToCreateClass underTest = new MySlowToCreateClass(path);
        int actualResult = underTest.calculate();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }

    [DataRow("C:/Users/path1", 5)]
    [DataRow("C:/Users/path", 170)]
    [TestMethod]
    public void AdditionTest(string path, int expectedResult)
    {
        MySlowToCreateClass underTest = new MySlowToCreateClass(path);
        int actualResult = underTest.calculateOtherThing();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it in C#?

Comment: NUnit supports test parameterization.  https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parameterized-Tests

Comment: But these are only for test methods, isn't it? I want to parameterize the whole class execution.

Comment: NUnit2 (since 2.5) supports [parameterized test fixtures](https://nunit.org/docs/2.5/testFixture.html), if using a legacy framework is an acceptable work-around. I believe 3 has a proposal, but not a complete implementation. XUnit 2 decided not to implement this feature, I'm unsure of it's status in XUnit 3.